# How to make image responsive on text hover

Tags: javascript, css, hover, responsive

I'm working on my website, where I made some custom changes for the home page. I wanted to display the images only when the user hovers over the text. 
I have absolutely no knowledge on this topic / coding in general so I’m glad that I was able to make it work somehow for desktop, but I’m stuck what to do to make the images responsive.  I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this, here's what I was able to work out so far:

```js
<script language="Javascript">
function ShowPicture(id,Source) {
    if (Source=="1") {
        if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "show"
        else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "visible"
        else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "visible"
    } else if (Source=="0") {
        if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "hide"
        else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "hidden"
        else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "hidden"
    }
}
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
#Style2 { 
    position: fixed;
    width:650px;
    height:440px;
    top: 110px;
    right: 55px;
    visibility:hidden; 
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
</style>

</style>

<a href="" onMouseOver="ShowPicture('Style2',1)" onMouseOut="ShowPicture('Style2',0)"><h3>a<h3><h4>b<h4></a>
<div id="Style2"><img src="></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
#Style2 > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

That will make image always fit container.
Example:

```js
function ShowPicture(id,Source) {
if (Source=="1"){
if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "show"
else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "visible"
else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "visible"
}
else
if (Source=="0"){
if (document.layers) document.layers[''+id+''].visibility = "hide"
else if (document.all) document.all[''+id+''].style.visibility = "hidden"
else if (document.getElementById) document.getElementById(''+id+'').style.visibility = "hidden"
}
}
```

```css
#Style2 { 
    position: fixed;
    width:250px;
    height:440px;
    top: 110px;
    right: 55px;
 visibility:hidden; 
}
h1 {
   margin-top: 100px;
  }

#Style2 > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://kirakoroknai.com/project/bock-albus" onMouseOver="ShowPicture('Style2',1)" onMouseOut="ShowPicture('Style2',0)">
  <h3>absence</h3><h4>— visual identity</h4>
</a>

<div id="Style2"><img src="https://i1.wp.com/kirakoroknai.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/kira-koroknai-absence-graphic-design-exhibition-identity-13.jpg?fit=2200%2C1760"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's not the problem, you just need to learn media queries and change the width based on screen size, for example for mobile you would add to css: `@media (max-width: 320px) { #Style2 { width: 160px; } }`

Answer (score -1):

I dont really see the point of using JS in this case... you can do all with CSS (as far as i understand the question)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- head content -->
        <style>
            #img {
                display: none;
            }
            #link:hover + #img {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="link">Hover me</div>
        <img id="img" src="http://lorempizza.com/240/240">
    </body>
</html>
```

maybe its not this your looking for, but i tried to help ;)